# run second Rewrite condition and rule after the first rule is executed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file is:

```
# remove "www"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# add trailing slash "/"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*(?:^|/)[^/\.]+)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# other rules needed
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^old-link/$ https://example.com/new-link/ [R=301,L]
```

With this my goal is to make http://www.example.com/something-after redirect to https://example.com/something-after
After that I wish to add "/" at the end: https://example.com/something-after/

However, I have tested this in a online tester and it says that the "*The tests are stopped, using a different host will cause a redirect*" on the first rule and for this reason the second rule is never met.

Comment: Are you hosting multiple domains and/or subdomains on this one account or is `example.com` and `www.example.com` the only two hostnames?

Comment: It is true, that the rewriting process is terminated after the redirection to another host. _BUT_ for the request the browser sends to _that_ host another rewriting process is started ...

Comment: @MrWhite, yes the problem here is that I have multiple domains. If I didn't maybe I could write other kind of rules

Comment: @arkascha thank you very much. I think that I understood and maybe I am seeing a problem where it doesn't exist

Comment: Ok, that's not a problem... if you didn't have multiple domains then the rules could be simplified a bit, as the `RewriteCond` directive to check the `Host` header (on two of the rules) would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tested this in a online tester and it says that the "The tests are stopped, using a different host will cause a redirect" on the first rule and for this reason the second rule is never met.

Most online testers only make a single pass (in a single request) through the directives. On a real server, multiple passes (and multiple requests) can occur.

There isn't really an issue with these directives, except that it will potentially trigger multiple redirects. eg. a request for `https://www.example.com/foo` will trigger *two* external redirects. The first to `https://example.com/foo` (removing www) and the 2nd to `https://example.com/foo/` (appending the trailing slash). At the extreme, a request for `https://www.example.com/old-link` (no trailing slash) will trigger *three* external redirects.

These multiple redirects can be avoided by simply reordering the rules and explicitly including the scheme+hostname in the redirect to append the trailing slash (currently the 2nd rule), as you have done in the other two rules. Also, allowing an optional trailing slash on the `/old-link/` rule.

For example:

```
# Specific redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^old-link/?$ https://%1/new-link/ [R=301,L]

# Add trailing slash "/"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*(?:^|/)[^/.]+)$ https://%1/$1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove "www"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(example\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Now, only one rule ever needs to be processed. The removal of www, appending a slash and redirecting `/old-link` are all handled by a single rule.

Other minor changes:

- I've captured the domain in the *CondPattern* and used a `%1` backreference in the *substitution* string. This simply saves having to explicitly repeat the domain name in the *substitution* string.
- Removed `$` (end-of-string anchor) from the *CondPattern* to allow for a FQDN that ends in a dot.
- Added the `NC` flag to the `RewriteCond` directive. (A bot could potentially request a mixed case `Host` header.)
- No need to backslash-escape literal dots inside a regex character class. The dot carries no special meaning here.

However, another issue here is you don't currently have an HTTP to HTTPS redirect. You could add this as the *last* rule:

```
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This is just a standard HTTP to HTTPS redirect, assuming the SSL cert is installed directly on the application server.

By placing the rule *last* you only need to check for `example.com` (and not `www.example.com`) since the request must already have been canonicalized (to remove the www subdomain) by the preceding rule (if needed).