# Avoid redirect chaining for https non www. htacess

Tags: loops, .htaccess, redirect, chain

after endless searching on Google and various forums i cannot find a method on redirecting a site correctly without any chains. is it possilble to redirect to a single url and avoid the chaining? Below is the code i'm using at the moment

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

At the moment this seems to generate 2 or 3 redirects e.g
`http://example.co.uk/example-page/` gets redirected to:

- `http://www.example.co.uk/example-page/`
- `https://www.example.co.uk/example-page/`

or if you don't include a trailing slash `http://example.co.uk/example-page` it goes to:

- `http://example.co.uk/example-page/`
- `http://www.example.co.uk/example-page/`
- `https://www.example.co.uk/example-page/`

is it possible to simply go straight to `https://www.example.co.uk/example-page/` no matter if we include a trailing slash or not, include or don't include www. or http or whats the best way to write this?

my knowledge of htaccess files is very limited but i'm eager to learn how this all works and how it can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

The output you are seeing is not consistent with the `.htaccess` directives as posted, so you maybe seeing a cached response. Make sure your browser cache is clear before testing and test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

For instance, in the output from both your examples, the non-www to www redirect is not changing the protocol (ie. it's redirecting from `http://example` to `http://www.example`). However, your directive in `.htaccess` explicitly includes the `https://` protocol. So either something else is triggering this redirect, or you are seeing a cached response from an earlier attempt?

Also, both your examples are redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS in the last redirect. However, there is no HTTP to HTTPS redirect in the `.htaccess` directives you posted. This redirect likely triggered by your application, after `.htaccess` has finished.

The reduce the number of redirects to one, you need to explicitly include the protocol + canonical hostname in the first redirect that appends the trailing slash.

For example:

```
# Append trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ https://www.example.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

# Redirect Non-www to www + HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The HTTP to HTTPS redirect assumes the SSL cert is installed directly on your application server and you are not using a front-end proxy / CDN / load balancer etc.

Another related question: [run second Rewrite condition and rule after the first rule is executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70114959/run-second-rewrite-condition-and-rule-after-the-first-rule-is-executed)